# Java Printing the lines of a File after reading it

Tags: java

I'm just a beginner java programmer and I have no idea on how to print lines after the file is read.

I got a text file like this

- Jordan House 87.4
- Anthony Mason 76.5
- Austin Twumasi 90.5
- Ciprian Rhodes 66.9
- Darrell Poon 75.2

and I was just wondering how will I print line whose grades are above 70.30

here is my code

```
 public class Question1 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        // Create a Scanner object attached to the keyboard
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        // Write your code here!!!!
        System.out.print ("Enter the input filename: " );
        String filename = in.nextLine();
        // Open the datafile
        File file = new File(filename);
        // set the delimited to be a ,
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
        double avgGrade = 0;
        double totalAvgGrade = 0;
        int numStu = 0;
        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;



        while (inFile.hasNext())  
        {
            firstName = inFile.next();
            lastName = inFile.next();
            String gradeAvg = inFile.next();
            avgGrade = Double.parseDouble(gradeAvg);
            totalAvgGrade += avgGrade;
            numStu++;


        }
        double average = totalAvgGrade/numStu;
        System.out.printf("%s %.2f \n","Average grade is", average);
        System.out.println("Students with grade > average ");
        System.out.printf("%s %10s %10s", "First", "Last", "Score");
        if ( avgGrade > average)
            {
                System.out.printf("\n %s %10s %.2f" ,firstName , lastName , avgGrade);
            }



    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Inside and at the end of your while-loop, you need something like `System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + avgGrade);`

Comment: In order to print the list *after* printing the average, you need to save the data in a `List` of some class that you create to hold the 3 values of  student (← good name for the class, i.e. `Student`).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple if-statement. Seems like you’re using more code than needed. While loops wouldn’t work the best for this case, though I guess you can use them!

```
If(grades > 70) 
{
    System.out.println(*code code code*);
}
```